# Trying to change text on button in Python .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to teach myself Python Kivy and I have been working with this calculator program. I want to make the text for exponent different than what it being processed. It is normally ** but I want it to show ^ on the button. How do I get it show one thing and put in a different thing in the entry.text += self.text part. 
The other way I was thinking was trying to use a decorator, but I am not sure how to do that for an operator like that.

Any ideas?

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics','resizable',1)

class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def calculate(self,calculation):
        if calculation:
            try: 
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "Error"


class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()

calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()
```

calculator.kv

````
# Custom button 
<CustButton@Button>: 
    font_size: 32

# Define id so I can refer to the CalcGridLayout 
# class functions 
# Display points to the entry widget 
<CalcGridLayout>: 
    id: calculator 
    display: entry 
    rows: 6
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10



    # Where input is displayed 
    BoxLayout: 
        TextInput: 
            id: entry 
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False

    # When buttons are pressed update the entry 
    BoxLayout: 
        spacing: 5

        CustButton: 
            text: "+"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "-"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton: 
            text: "*"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "/"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "("
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton: 
            text: ")"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton: 
            text: "**"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text




    BoxLayout: 
        spacing: 5
        CustButton: 
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "4"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "5"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "AC"
            on_press: entry.text = "" 

    BoxLayout: 
        spacing: 5
        CustButton: 
            text: "6"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "7"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "8"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "9"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "0"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text 
        CustButton: 
            text: "="
            on_press: calculator.calculate(entry.text) 
      ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood, this will resolve:

```
CustButton: 
            text: "^"
            on_press: entry.text += "**"
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! I have been driving myself nutty trying to figure this out!!